# WSO2 Api Manager Performance stats

Tags: performance, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I want to get an idea about the Wso2 Api Manager performance capabilities. I saw in one of the documents that have mentioned, the API Manager works best when there are 350 to 30000 calls per second to the API Gateway. I want to verify this fact or find more insights into the API Gateway performance.